# Blazor MAUI app crashes on start in Release config on Android

Tags: c#, android, blazor, .net-6.0, maui

I have written a .NET MAUI Blazor app and have run into an issue where it is now crashing as soon as the application loads. I am getting zero useful feedback to help me track down what the bug is in my code which is causing this.

This only happens when running the Release version of the app, but is reproducible both by taking a compiled `-Signed.apk` to install on the device, or when attempting to run the application in Release mode via Visual Studio (debugging over USB).

When run in Debug, the application works, however this is not an apples to apples comparison, as the Debug version of the app seems to have a different AppData folder (no data from the Release config is available).

I have scoured my code for the few places where I had done some `#if/else DEBUG` directives, and with them commented out, the issue persists.

The only log information I have available thus far is below:

```
08-14 19:49:13.385  Samsung SM-A716U    Error   18021   .My.Ap  * Assertion at /__w/1/s/src/mono/mono/mini/aot-runtime.c:3678, condition `is_ok (error)' not met, function:decode_patch, module 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui.dll.so' is unusable (GUID of dependent assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView doesn't match (expected 'B27A41A6-37DA-48F5-8E28-EC47FA31EBC7', got '6BA9D71B-392E-479A-9EF5-13DA5572959A')).

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
08-14 19:49:13.386  Samsung SM-A716U    Error   18021   libc    Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 18021 (.My.App), pid 18021 (.My.App)

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
08-14 19:49:13.602  Samsung SM-A716U    Error   18054   DEBUG   Cmdline: NS.My.App

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
08-14 19:49:13.602  Samsung SM-A716U    Error   18054   DEBUG   pid: 18021, tid: 18021, name: .My.App  >>> NS.My.App <<<

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
08-14 19:49:13.738  Samsung SM-A716U    Error   1279    ActivityManager android.util.Log$TerribleFailure: Removing process that hasn't been killed: ProcessRecord{a2b455e 0:NS.My.App/u0a575}
    at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:438)
    at android.util.Slog.wtfStack(Slog.java:206)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.removeLruProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:3506)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.removeLruProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3184)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3635)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.removeProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:3724)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.removeProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:3661)
    at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(AppErrors.java:787)
    at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication(AppErrors.java:584)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:9711)
    at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:119)

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
08-14 19:49:13.738  Samsung SM-A716U    Error   1279    ActivityManager android.util.Log$TerribleFailure: Removing process that hasn't been killed: ProcessRecord{a2b455e 0:NS.My.App/u0a575}
    at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:438)
    at android.util.Slog.wtfStack(Slog.java:206)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.removeLruProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:3506)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.removeLruProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3184)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3635)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.removeProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:3724)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.removeProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:3661)
    at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(AppErrors.java:787)
    at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication(AppErrors.java:584)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:9711)
    at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:119)
```

Answer (score 3):

The thing that worked to me was deleting the **obj** and **bin** folders.
The Clean Solution command didn't work, I had to manually delete everything generated by the build process.

Comment: It's really strange but for me too, deleting `bin` and `obj` brought me one step further. Now it doesn't crash on startup, it just gets stuck on loading.

Answer (score 2):

You may of started a project before the last preview update, I too had this error and took some debugging to find it.

Go into your NuGet Package Manager and update Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView to version 6.0.8

This solved the same error as you had for me.

Comment: This was also my issue, wish they could have put build warnings in...